# Convert a 1-based array to a 0-based array in Julia

Tags: julia

I'm writing some numerical code in which it would be more convenient to use 0-based indexing than Julia's default 1-based indexing. Julia does support 0-based indexing, but the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/devdocs/offset-arrays/) for it is aimed squarely at developers, so I'm a bit confused about how to use it.

Specifically: if I call `rand(10,10)` I get a 10x10 array with indexes from 1 to 10. Is there a simple equivalent command that will return an array with indexes from 0 to 9 instead? Or alternatively, can I easily convert this to a 0-based array instead of a 1-based one?

Comment: You can check out https://github.com/JuliaArrays/OffsetArrays.jl.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński thanks, that's very useful! So it seems that the command `OffsetArray(rand(10,10),0:9,0:9)` does what I want. Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: Yes (some placeholder for 15 chars in comment)

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński thanks. I've posted a self-answer. (If you care about points, I'm happy to delete it and let you post an answer instead, but I assume you don't.)

Answer (score 6):

I'm posting a self-answer because the question was answered by Bogumił Kamiński in the comments.

There is some user-level documentation [here](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/OffsetArrays.jl), though at the time of writing it is rather short and consists entirely of examples, so one has to infer the intended semantics and guess at best practices.

However, it seems the command

`OffsetArray(rand(10,10),0:9,0:9)`

achieves what I was asking for, and Bogumił Kamiński confirmed that this is the correct way to do it, so one can guess that this doesn't needlessly copy the array, etc.

One hopes that some proper documentation will be written at some point, since this is quite an important feature. (One hopes this for many important features of Julia.)

Comment: You can check out that this array is only a wrapper around the original array by writing `x = rand(10,10); y = OffsetArray(rand(10,10),0:9,0:9); parent(y) === x` which produces `true`.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński one can certainly do that if one knows about the `parent` method. (Which I do now - thank you!)

Comment: and that is why I have written the comment :).

Comment: @Nathaniel, often users are the best people to contribute documentation, because they have a much better sense for what confused them than the people who wrote the code. If you would, please click on the README.md file for OffsetArrays, then click on the little pencil icon, and start improving it!

Comment: Um, that's certainly not true. Anyone with a browser can make improvements; if you can also read code or just try the demos, you have a good shot of understanding how the package is supposed to work (it's a very simple package). Any changes you suggest will be vetted by someone with commit privileges before merging, so there's no chance whatsoever that you'll break anything.

Comment: For the record, I frequently contribute documentation to other people's packages, and they are usually grateful. The point is to get both the code and the docs up to snuff, in a way that someone besides the package developer can understand. It doesn't matter how one gets there as long as it happens. There is nothing silly about contributing.